# Why has io.sort.record.percent been removed?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

Why has the `io.sort.record.percent` property been removed from Hadoop 1.x onwards?

Answer (score 3):

It's there in 2.x but the only difference is that its name has changed:

> **mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb**: The total amount of buffer memory to use while sorting files, in megabytes. By default, gives each merge stream 1MB, which should minimize seeks.

Default value is still 100 mb. Please find more information on [this link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.6/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml).

Comment: That's incorrect. Link you provide is for r0.23. The "old" equivalent for `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` is `io.sort.mb` see: [Hadoop Deprecated Properties](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html). As for the one in question (`io.sort.record.mb` ), it doesn't have an equivalent in the newer Hadoop but can be still set using same name and is very much in effect (Made some deep investigation: seems to limit `mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb` by it's value) so if you have specified 100MB and the other as 0.17 it will basically use 83MB for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

**io.sort.record.percent** is a percentage applying to **io.sort.mb** (old name).

Map output data is placed in an in-memory buffer. When the buffer fills up, the framework sorts it and then spills to disk.  A separate thread merges the sorted on-disk files into a single larger sorted file. The buffer consists of two parts: a section with contiguous raw output data and a metadata section that holds pointers for each record into the raw data section. In MR1, the sizes of these sections were fixed, controlled by **io.sort.record.percent**, which says how much percent of the io.sort.mb space is used for metadata secton. This meant that, without proper tuning of this parameter, if a job had many small records, the metadata section could fill up much more quickly than the raw data section. The buffer would be spilled to disk before it was entirely full. This affects performance.

[MAPREDUCE-64](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-64) fixed this issue in MR2 by allowing the two sections to share the same space and vary in size. Thus io.sort.record.percent is no longer required to minimize the number of spills in MR2. That's why this property has been removed